# Python: Map with class method which requires arguments

Tags: python, dictionary, pyqt5

I need to call a method for a set of arguments with PyQt5's `QTableWidget`, particularly `PyQt5.QTableWidget.setItem`.

I have this list of strings,

```
row = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

and I need to put every element in a column of the table, except for the first. What I tried is

```
items = [ QTableWidgetItem(r) for r in row[1:] ]
arguments = zip([rowNumber+1]*(len(row)-1), range(1,len(row)), items)
putItem = lambda x:tableWidget.setItem(*x)
import itertools
itertools.starmap(putItem, arguments)
```

I also tried with map and no zip of the arguments, but nothing seems to work. I know I could do a `for` loop on the arguments, but I wanted the "more elegant" map solution.

The main issue is that no information is displayed in the table, though there are no error reports nor warning nor anything.

Thanks!

Comment: "nothing seems to work" Do you get an error? Does the table contain no entries? What is the exact problem?

Comment: The table contains no entries, though no error is reported. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop is more elegant although not as terse, IMHO.

When you create a generator (as with starmap), you have to consume it to execute code.
For example, pass it to `list()`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, though I have to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer.  Now I have to fix the issue that the rows are displaced, but that's not the point of the answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the heck of it, here's the sane way to write this code:

```
for column, text in enumerate(row[1:], 1):
    tableWidget.setItem(rowNumber + 1, column, QTableWidgetItem(text))
```